# Displaying attribute of ViewBag depending on the selected item from DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display the price of the selected item in the textbox in the view. For example, a product selected from the DLL has a price of 10 € and it should be displayed in the view. Can someone help?

Controler

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Product product = DB.Products.Find(id);
        ViewBag.Formats = new SelectList(storeDB.Format, "FormatID", "FormatName", "Price");
        ViewBag.Foo = "Some Value";     //test
        return View(product);
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Formats", ViewBag.Formats as SelectList, new { id = "DDLFormatsID" })
            @Html.Display("Price")        //displays nothing
            @Html.Display("Foo")          //working properly
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

[image: This can explain more.]

Update:

[image: update]

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please try to make some changes to explain your problem better.

Comment: It seems to me that now is good.

Comment: What about using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)`?

Comment: Price is in the ViewBag ,not in the model.

Comment: Use `@Html.Display("Price")` then. The string (`"Price"`) has to match with the name of the property in the `ViewBag`

Comment: unfortunately does not display the value of ViewBag...

Comment: I've test it using MVC4 but I believe it should work in MVC3. If you put some value in the ViewBag like this `ViewBag.Foo = "Some Value"` then you can display that value using `@Html.Display("Foo")`. I'm sure that works

Comment: That's right, if I have a value in ViewBag works. But in the case of the list which I do, not see anything...

Comment: Sorry. I'm still confused. What property of the ViewBag do you want to show? Are you referring to `ViewBag.Formats`? If you have more properties in the `ViewBag` please show them in code.

Comment: I have upgraded my code already. I think... I described my problem wrong...

Comment: I see. Please try to edit your question. I think I'm close to understand it.

Comment: better? even add something? thank you for your patience.

Comment: No problem. Wait a minute I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the order of the parameters in the constructor of the `SelectList`. I changed this line and it worked as you expected, showing the prices.

`ViewBag.Formats = new SelectList(storeDB.Format, "FormatID", "Price");`

You can check for the use of each parameter in the constructor. The first is for the data, the second is the name of the property that will hold the data to be send on the post, the third is the name of the property to be displayed.

**Answer to the updated question:**

If you want to show some value depending on the value in the dropdown then you can do it using javascript. First You have to identify the control to put your value, I'll use a span but you can use a textbox, etc. Then you subscribe to the change event of the dropdown and change the content of the first control every time.

Note that I'm using the value of the select to store the prices. If you want to receive the value as the id of the item you cannot use this approach. You need to store the prices in another place, you can use hidden elements.

*You have to reference the jQuery library in the view.*

The code is this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Product product = DB.Products.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Formats = new SelectList(storeDB.Format, "Price", "FormatName");
    return View(product);
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Formats", ViewBag.Formats as SelectList, new { id = "DDLFormatsID" })
            <span id="priceHolder"></span>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Formats").change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var selectedValue = $this.val();
            $('#priceHolder').html(selectedValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! And do you know how to leave the value as before and the price displayed in this field, which I marked in the picture? I did the update.

Comment: I'm afraid you changed the question. Wait a moment. I'll think about it.

Comment: @user3128303 Check my updated answer. Please tell me if that works for you. If you need to receive the ids in the form post, tell me to update my answer.

Comment: Nothing displays. when I changed the `$("#Formats").change(function ()` at `$("#DDLFormatsID").change(function ()` displays 0 or 1 (selectedValue). I added `alert("$this =" + $this)` and I noticed that `#Formats` script is not executed. To sum up, still not price...

Comment: while `var SelectedValue = $this.text();` simultaneously displays the "FM-1 FM-2".